# Classic ASP VBScript Fiddle?

Tags: web-development, web-services, asp.net, vb.net

I know, I know, but I'm in need of a classic ASP development environment to help with updating legacy code (because I've forgotten ASP). The goal is *not* to convert this code to something modern, rather minor changes need to be made. It will all be scrapped eventually. Today, I'm looking for something similar to [PHPFiddle.org](http://PHPFiddle.org) or [dotnetfiddle.net](https://dotnetfiddle.net/) for classic ASP using VBScript. Just to jog the memory, ASP files looks like this:

```
<%
If Len(Request.QueryString("name")) > 0 Then
     Response.Cookies("name") = Request.QueryString("name") 
End If

Response.Write "Welcome " & Server.HTMLEncode(Response.Cookies("name")) & "!"
%>
```

The production system is not to be touched. That means no experimenting in some hidden subfolder. What online fiddles are there for classic ASP? I haven't been able to find any. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I don't know if this is helpful, but IIS comes built-in in most Windows editing (pro, enterprise, ultimate) and on Windows Server. If you're using Windows, you can just install it and have it use a non-standard port so it does not interfere with your (presumably) existing other web server.

Answer (score 0):

For VBScript or ASP Classic, or for modeling VBA (Visual Basic for Applications) such as macros used in Microsoft Excel (but without specific Excel libraries), there is:

http://VBFiddle.net

I developed this website/script a few weeks ago specifically as a Thank you! to all of the contributors of Stack Exchange, Stack Overflow, and all of their universe of sites, and I find it very useful for quick prototyping or to show someone my VBScript code... for example with VBScript's RegEx engine which has some quirks specific to VBScript.

VBFiddle.net does not yet support saving your VBScript on the website, but you can save your VBScript to say jSFiddle.net and link to that, and instruct people to copy and paste into http://VBFiddle.net. I will add saving support to VB Fiddle / Visual Basic Classic Fiddle if there is enough interest.

Enjoy!

Comment: Update 2023: Site VBFiddle.net is dead/Domain name no longer exists on public internet.

Answer (score -1):

Desktop editors like Context and Notepad++ provide syntax highlighters for Classic ASP. Microsoft Visual InterDev provides intellisense and code completion. It was part of Visual Studio 6. Unfortunately, current MSDN subscription provide access to VB6 but not Interdev. However old MSDN subscribers may have already obtained Interdev and be willing to sell it on Amazon.

I am not aware of online editors.